# How do I store the row IDs from the columns used to make a view, for possible updates to the rows the view comprises?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, primefaces, derby, java-ee-7

I'm using Eclipselink, JAX-RS, and Primefaces. Some of my tables will be joined into Views (or possibly just Joins) that will populate the Primefaces interface for the user. Eventually, I think the user would want to update some of the rows and columns that comprise what the user is seeing.

How and where can the rowIDs be stored?  `sessionStorage.setItem("foo", "bar");` ? or, maybe there is some JavaEE function that I could use?

Answer (score 0):

I'll replace the @RequestScoped annotation on my client bean with @viewscoped. I'll add custom methods on the rest facades and entity classes for the Views I created in Derby,  that will pass the rowIDs to my client bean.